# Microsoft Lists bug or feature when missing the edit option of a column

Tags: list, power-automate

Microsoft Lists are part of Microsoft Automated Flows.

If you want to automate the loading of an excel file or csv file, you are probably going to want your Microsoft Power Automate to load this data in a List.

So I think it is important that I figure out how to fix something that I have found.

Here is how I found this strange thing.  I have a flow that does not work and, in the process of debugging this flow, a simpler flow has been made THAT DOES WORK.  So, logically, if I slowly, step by step, compare the two and gradually make changes to the one that works, I will be able to find the bug.  The problem is, in the process of carefully looking at the one that does not work, I found something.  I have been categorizing the column types in the main List in SharePoint and I am unable to see the details of the column by clicking on "Edit".

Here, I will show you.  the column called "Total Time" has an edit menu option.  This allows me to see the specifics of the column data setting.

[image]

The column  in the List that if for "Employee ID" is mysteriously missing the Edit menu option.  What would cause this anomaly and how can it be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect "Employee ID" isn't a true column and instead a meta-data column that has been renamed possible from "Created By" or "Modified By".

Or "Employee ID" is the "Title" column that has been renamed.

Best to go into List Settings, then click on the "Employee ID" column, then look at URL/address to see what the Field name is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the column that can not be edited (much) is Microsoft's idea of what is called in database terms as a "primary index".  I figured it out by a number of clues.  One is that, no matter what, when a list is created there is already a column defined that can not be deleted.  As you build the list and add content, this predetermined list has content in bold.  A developer will also find that tutorials of building automated flows will include using this column as if it were a primary index of unique fields.  And the fields are set to be unique.  That is why it can only be renamed but not changed to allow for duplicate data in more than one row.